# Appveyor build failure

Tags: build, atom-editor, appveyor

I am creating a build with Appveyor on Github use `devtool` https://github.com/atom/atom-keymap. Although Travis builds success, Appveyor builds still appear error!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know real root cause, but I think I can help with a way to troubleshoot this. Basically you can connect to AppVeyor VM via RDP and debug it. Here are the steps:

Insert `- ps: $blockRdp = $true; iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/appveyor/ci/master/scripts/enable-rdp.ps1'))` before `- npm run ci` in your appveyor.yml file.

In RDP run the following:

```
cd c:\projects\atom-keymap
npm run compile
npm run lint
```

This will bring you to the state to get a repro and debug (because `npm run ci` is `npm run compile && npm run lint && npm run test`).

To get a repro `npm run test`.

To debug the problem, do something like this:

```
devtool  --console node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --colors spec/helpers/setup.js spec/* --break
```

(this will let you debug step-by-step)

or

```
devtool  --console node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --colors spec/helpers/setup.js spec/* --watch
```

(this will let you see a lot of error details)

This is the same what `npm run test` does, but without switch to quit on error and with debug options.

I went this route myself till this point but my limited knowledge of this npm module did not let me to dig till the root cause.

Comment: By the way I assume this `devtool` command works on your Windows machine. If not, better to make it work locally before trying to run this on AppVeyor...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it.